# Sinatra + Mustache + CSS issues

Tags: css, sinatra, mustache

I am trying to make my first Sinatra + Mustache site but I am having issues including css files for my mustache templates to use. Including them like a normal css file won't work and neither will putting them in a /public/css/mystyle.css format.

Does anyone know how to do this properly?

thanks

Comment: Not enough information. What does not work exactly? Does the CSS file fail to load? Is the path incorrect? Are you getting an error in the server console? On the browser console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that I'm understanding your question properly, but if your css file is in `public/css/mystyle.css` you should include it with

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/mystyle.css">
```

There are several reasons I can think of, for it not to happen. You have:

- omitted leading `/`
- reconfigured `public_folder` like this: `set :public_folder, "path to other folder"`
- changed root folder, so now your public folder is `new_root/public`
- set up some paths in your `configure.ru` file

Comment: that is what I thought would work too but for some reason it doesn't load the file. I can see, in chrome dev tools, that none of my .css files are loading and all have broken links...

Comment: @JonRose I've expanded answer a bit. Do you see any other file in your `public` dir?

Comment: i think this was related to my other post about RVM, gems, directories, and permissions. Now with my leading ./ additions and using 1.9.2, everything is up and running, and with CSS!  thanks again for all the help